# Update site with jQuery and dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i'm trying to do a simple print of some database data when the user change the selected information in my dropdown.

i have found out how to give me the information from the dropdown and output it into my textfield..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#date").datepicker();
    $("#formGender").change(function()
{
    /* setting currently changed option value to option variable */
    var option = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    /* setting input box value to selected option value */
    $("#showoption").val(option);   
});
});
</script>
```

So what i really want, is that i want to do a MySQL call with the information i get from this dropdown.

something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'option' = customerNo
```

i can read that i need to make a seperate file and call the function and return it with GET/POST but i'm kinda stuck :( and could need some help in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AJAX** is the thing you need,

When ever user chage the value of dropdown call **AJAX** to get the values from database, so your jQuery could would look something like this,

```
$("#formGender").change(function()
{
    /* setting currently changed option value to option variable */
    var option = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    /* setting input box value to selected option value */
    $("#showoption").val(option); 

    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'PATH/TO/YOUR_PHP_FILE_NAME.php',
       data:{'inputval':option},
       success: function(data)
       {
           // access returned data here..
       },
   });
});
```

Now your PHP file will look something like this,

**YOUR_PHP_FILE_NAME.php**

```
<?php
    $inputval=$_GET['inputval'];
    $sql_Query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE option = '".$inputval."'";

    // Perform database operations and other things.
    // Return response here using echo.
    // You can use header('Content-Type: application/json'); to return JSON data.
?>
```

Handle those returned data in **.success()** callback of the **$.ajax** function.

> Make sure you use bindParam method to access the database data to
>   avoid SQL injections.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

The file i try to access is called data.php and is in the same destination.
so url:'data.php' should be fine i guess.

i just tried to echo a simple string back to see it work.. But I failed :(

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it helps you. It will also help future SO users.

Comment: it works... had a missing } in my script... will accept answer ! THX alot